# Image changes in Docker are wiped after using Docker save

Tags: docker

I am running into an issue where I can see the correct modifications made to a Docker image when I run it, but these changes do not persist in the resulting .tar file after using Docker save.

**Background:** While this flow is not best practice/ideal I did not have the original Dockerfile to recreate the image with the changes, so I reverted to modifying from the steps below instead.

For ease we'll call the base image "original" and the modified image "newimage".

Here are the steps taken:

- `docker load --input original.tar`
- `docker run -it --entrypoint bash original`
- In the container, did a small line edit with sed:
  `sed -i 's/original_line/updated_line/g' <filename>`(also tried making this update with VIM & nano successfully to test editor vs. edit in place differences, but this did not change the outcome of the .tar at all)
- Exited the container
- Restarted the same container
- `docker commit <containerID> newimage`
  (to get a snapshot of container changes made for the new image)
- `docker run -it --entrypoint bash newimage<br>`
- Verified the image had the right updates via cat file view
- `docker save newimage > newimage.tar`
- Tar generates successfully, but when I unzip and go to the various layers, I can see that my line changes are no longer present in the expected file.

I've also tried recreating this image via the Dockerfile build method, using "FROM original", with the same behavior. I see volumes can be helpful with data persistence, but I'm not sure if they're needed in this case, given the new image has the necessary changes present.

I do not think it is just an issue with the tar layer view, as my program is still throwing errors for the old line (as if no changes were ever made). But, who knows. :)

Any ideas of what may be happening? Docker save documentation is a bit limited in the official documentation, and I have tried most all of the other related solutions posts, but I will keep digging.

Comment: [UPDATE] I ended up using docker history https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/ to get the bulk of the original Dockerfile content and rebuild with edits that way. This took quite awhile to piece together and clean up though, so still very interested to see if anyone knows a solution that may be easier next time around!